# How to Prevent a terminal window from jumping to the end while running a script or similar?

Tags: linux, terminal

When I use `dnf` on *Fedora* or `pacman` on *Arch* to update my OS to the newest files via terminal command, it can sometimes be a long wait while the new files are being downloaded, so I like to scroll back up to the file list shown before I started the update process to guess where about in the overall list I currently am, so I can have a guess about how long it might take from here on.

The problem is the fact that since the last line constantly updates and changes the terminal window automatically jumps back down almost instantly and prevents me from reading anything -- including messages printed out by the installed packages themselves -- (or even scroll up far enough to get to where I want to).

Is there a way, to prevent the terminal window from jumping to the newest line, but stay were I am actually scrolling to? While I wouldn't mind if that can only be done via a switch, so that the window will either always or never scroll on its own, it would of course be preferrable if it stopped jumping the moment the scrollbar is **not** at the bottom and resumes the automatic scrolling when the scrollbar is returned there (which would be my intuition as to how such a thing **should** work).

Comment: It depends on what terminal software you're using. Some can be configured in their settings to behave as you described.

Comment: No special terminal software on either of the two distributions, just the standard `Terminal` they provide, but I will certainly dig deeper into their settings, maybe I just overlooked it.

Comment: You mention BOTH Fedora and Arch BUT not the terminal or terminal emulator in question.  for MOST gui terminals (aka getty) in the profiles or preferences section there is a 'auto-scroll' function that can be toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [GNOME Terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-scrolling.html.en) or [MATE Terminal](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal), you can disable scroll on output:

1. Right-mouse click your terminal window.
2. Go to Profiles » Profile Preferences
3. Go to the "Scrolling" tab.
4. Uncheck "Scroll on output".

[image: MATE Terminal » Editing Profile » Scrolling]